# How to config IIS so that it uses web.config of each folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, dotnetnuke-module

I am working on a `DotNetNuke` module and I need to put some settings in its `web.config`. So far I was using `IIS Express` for my development environment and everything was working fine.(The module has a `web.config` in its folder and it can read its settings from there while it's hosted on `IIS Express`)

Now I am testing my module on a `DNN` that is hosted on `IIS` and the module can't find it's settings ( It seems that `IIS` doesn't look at web.config files in other folders rather that its main `web.config`)

The question is how should I configure `IIS` so that my module can access its web.config in its folder ?

Comment: This question itself is improper. You settings are loaded by ASP.NET, not IIS. As IIS does read every web.config but it only takes care of things under <system.webServer>.

Comment: OK but as far as I know ASP.net behavior is different for IIS Express and IIS

Comment: The differences come from the config files if you compare. The two server products share the same code to read configuration, so if you get the same config there should be no diff at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in IIS you'll have to convert your folder to an application (right-click on that folder), that will create a new AppDomain root and be using a different global.asax, bin folder and web.config.